# Full process for compiling/linking and using MATLAB coder generated C++ files

Tags: c++, matlab, makefile

I've been struggling with this for a very long time. 
Using MATLAB's coder, I've generated a C++ code, but I'm not sure how to implement it in my main file.

This is the directory containing the MATLAB generated C++ code. Could somebody please walk me through how to use this code in another main file? 
(The whole process of making a make file, include statements, etc;) I really would appreciate it if the explanation is specific and thorough.

Here is one of the header files that I need to include (IOPfinal.h)

```
#ifndef IOPFINAL_H
#define IOPFINAL_H

// Include Files
#include <math.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "rt_nonfinite.h"
#include "rtwtypes.h"
#include "IOPfinal_types.h"

// Function Declarations
extern double IOPfinal(const emxArray_real_T *wavelength, const emxArray_real_T *
  intensity, double range, const emxArray_real_T *polymat);

#endif
```

I've heard that there are makefiles that are also provided by MATLAB but I'm not sure exactly how to use them and what I should do after using that makefile either. The code below is the main file that I intend to use.

```
#include "IOPfinal.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include "IOPfinal.h"
#include "IOPfinal_emxAPI.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    double *wavelength, *intensity;

    // some code to initialize wavelength and intensity

    emxArray_real_T *inputs, *outputs;

    inputs = emxCreateWrapper_real_T(wavelength, 1, 3);
    outputs = emxCreateWrapper_real_T(intensity, 1, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are 2 different things: MTLAB coder, compiles your matlab code into executable C files.   MATLAB MEX API, allows you to call C/C++ code from MATLAB fucntions. What do you want?

Comment: I am trying to use MATLAB coder. I want to be able to use my MATLAB function in a c++ code. Thanks!

Comment: Also I don't want to make executables out of my MATLAB code. I want to turn them into C++ functions which I can then include in my c++ code to use.

Comment: I see. Why do you never call `IOPfinal()` in your code?

Comment: Oh. I will be calling it eventually. (just haven't coded that part yet because emxCreateWrapper was not working) emxCreateWrapper_real_T is part of the MATLAB coder generated code and once I can get that working, I should be able to use the IOPfinal() function without too much trouble. I haven't been able to figure out how to do that yet because of compiling/linking problems. If you could walk me through the process of how to use MATLAB coder generated C++ functions, (compiling/linking) I would be very grateful

Comment: Btw I'm on a mac os using Xcode and gcc compiler